# Vuetify TextField is not rendering in my Vue + ASP core project

Tags: vuejs2, single-page-application, asp.net-core-2.0, vuetify.js

I am trying to use Text-fields in my template, but facing issues using it. My Project is an SPA in Vue + ASP.NET core.

Dependencies that I am using...

> ```
> "vue": "^2.5.2",  // But 2.3.4 is getting installed and i have no idea why
> "vue-loader": "^11.1.4",
> "vue-property-decorator": "^5.0.1",
> "vue-router": "^2.3.0",
> "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2", // But 2.3.4 is getting installed and i have no idea why
> "vuetify": "^0.16.6",
> ```

This is what i want to achieve.Its working fine in the codepen, here is the link 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQGdBq

```
            <v-layout row>
                <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>editetext</v-subheader>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field name="input-3"
                                  label="Label Text"
                                  value="Input text"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
```

But when used in my application it appears like this... basically unable to find the TextField Element as per the console log.

This is the result, Text field is not rendering 
[image: This is the result, Text field is not rendering]

The error that is printed in a console when the page is rendered.
[image: The error that is printed in console when the page is rendered.]

Has anyone faced this? Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding arbitrary `id` to a `v-text-field` (this counts as a workaround I think).

But if that doesn't work, try updating `vue` version - or if that doesn't work then update `vuetify` version as well.

I'm not sure but I think `vuetify` **requires** `vue` **version 2.4.** or higher anyway (perhaps you are getting a warning about vue version? check in console if you do, so update vue to required version).

(you can delete `vue` from `node_modules` and then run `npm install` again, so correct version should be installed, ie v2.5.2 and note that `vue-template-compiler` should also be same version as `vue`)

Comment: tried adding id, doesnt works, vue is not upgrading.. it sticks to 2.3.4 version. if i manually place vue 2.5.2 in node modules, still it reverts back to 2.3.4..

Comment: @Veer3383 don't manually place it, delete `vue` folder from `node_modules` and run `npm i vue`

Comment: did that many times.. also i dont wait for Visual studio to do that.. i deleted entire node modules folder and did npm install... i have 2.5.2 mentioned in package.json. but it still installs 2.3.4 . this is getting strange for me

Comment: @Veer3383 hmm do you have multiple `package.json` files maybe?

Comment: No, i dont even find package lock file.

Comment: @Veer3383 well, atm I'm not sure what to do with regards to that. It requires separate question I think (perhaps you could open one if you can't find solution by googling it). However, I'm very confident that updating versions as I've said will solve the problem (error) you are getting. Deleting `package-lock.json` (and then running `npm i`) probably should do the trick, but you say you don't have it? should be in same folder as `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with Visual studio here.

Reason: The files inside dist folder never gets updated, unlike how it does on standalone JS apps. So even after a particular component was updated vendor js and vendor css would never get updated.
deleting the dist folder solved the issue.